# Can't save core dump when using LLDB in android studio (osx)?

Tags: android, android-studio, native, lldb

When using LLDB to debug an android project that uses native libraries, i'm unable to export the core dump.

I run my application and get a SIGSEGV in the debugger. Then I open the LLDB console in Android Studio and get the following when i try to export the core dump.

```
(lldb) process save-core ./core-20180730-174318
error: Failed to save core file for process: no ObjectFile plugins were able to save a core for this process
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently `SaveCore` is only implemented for the MachO and PECOFF file formats, but not for ELF.  Feel free to file a request for this with bugs.llvm.org and somebody will get around to it at some point.  Or if you are interested in hacking on the debugger, you can have a go at implementing it yourself!  The people on the lldb-dev (lldb-dev@lists.llvm.org) list would be more than happy to help you out if you want to try your hand at this.